# Firebase security problems / authentication

Tags: javascript, http, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I created a Firebase Database and only by using the link

> https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/

I can make POST and GET requests without any authentication needed.
I assume these is a way to enable using auth, but could not find it.

Comment: Check your security rules

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 1):

Your security rules are probably open:

```
{
    "rules" : {
        ".read" : true,
        ".write" : true
    }
}
```

You'll have to update them to something else to restrict people.

Comment: Ok, I changed the rules. Now I get permission denied which is good. However, how can I authenticate myself. In the console, there are various ways by login, facebook, github and so but I just want to POST data via http request without having to log in. Where should I look for that.